# variable declaration in perl with multiple values

Tags: perl

I'm new to perl, I don't understand how does this line work.

```
my $Signal_Values;
$Signal_Values = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0];
```

TIA.

Comment: what is your requirement

Comment: Well what exactly don't you understand about it?

Answer (score 5):

The `[]` syntax creates an [array reference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Making-References).

References are scalar values so can be assigned to `$Signal_Values`.

Arrays are data structures designed to hold an ordered list of values.

Comment: Is that an array or scalar variable?

Comment: @Prawin — See the second paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Ok got it, Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

```
my $Signal_Values;
$Signal_Values = [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0];
```

is basically equivalent to

```
my $Signal_Values;
my @anon = (1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0);
$Signal_Values = \@anon;
```

`[ LIST ]` creates an array, assigns the results of `LIST` to the array, then returns a reference to the array. References are scalars, so they can be passed to a sub, returned by a sub and placed inside other arrays and hashes. (You can't do any of those things with arrays.)